# Как считывать что ввел пользователь и искать в базе данных?

Tags: python, sql, aiogram

Я пишу на aiogram.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Мне нужно чтобы пользователь вводил название архива и ему выводилось zip_pay и pass_pay

```
@dp.message_handler(state = FSMForms.history)
async def process_call(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['history'] = str(message.text)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, md.text(md.text('Вы ввели:', (data['history'])))),
        await db.user_hist(state)
    await state.finish()
```

И пытаюсь передать это сюда

```
async def user_hist(self, state):
        with self.connection:
            async with state.proxy() as data:
                for i in self.cursor.execute("SELECT `zip_pay`, `pass_pay` FROM `product` WHERE `zip_file` = ?", tuple(data.values)):
                    print(i)
```

но ничего не происходит

Comment: а если убрать кавычки внутри запроса? вот так: "SELECT zip_pay, pass_pay ... = ?"

Comment: я уже все решил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def user_hist_zip(self, zip_file):
        result_zip = ""
        with self.connection:
            for i in self.cursor.execute("SELECT `zip_pay`, `pass_pay` FROM `product` WHERE `zip_file` = ?", (zip_file,)):
                result_zip += f"{i[0]}"
            return result_zip
```